# What is the correct way to represent the Parallax angle?

Tags: observational-astronomy, star, parallax

I was recently reading about the parallax effect and hence had a doubt about the parallax angle.
A lot of places mention the parallax angle as `(θ1 + θ2)/2` while in some places it is just mentioned as `(θ1 + θ2)`.

**NOTE: Here θ1 and θ2 are the two angles between the two points of observation and some reference point like a extremely distant star.**

Now, I wanted to know that which of the above mentioned formulas is correct for the parallax angle and ***what is reason behind its correctness***. I also want to ask that what does the parallax angle actually represent/tell? Is it simply just the angle between the line of sights to a particular object like a star when viewed from two points or something else?

Also, when we use the parallax angle to calculate the distance to the star using parallax angle as `(θ1 + θ2)/2`then the distance to the star comes from *the sun to the star* **{by using trigonometry}** and when we calculate using the parallax angle as `(θ1 + θ2)` then the distance to the star comes from *the earth to the star* **{by using the formula: D = b/θ}**. So now which one of these is giving the correct distance?

Comment: You might want to add a source for those formulas, I can't imagine what they're trying to represent.  I would recommend looking up information on *parsec*, as that is generally the unit used to represent parallax.

Comment: What are $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$?

Comment: Here θ1 and θ2 are the two angles between the two points of observation and some reference point like a extremely distant star. It is also mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: A sketch might go a long way... when defining angles. And maybe then the answer also already becomes apparent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsec might give hints how to illustrate or explain the angles. I suspect it *might* read $(\theta_1 - \theta_2)/2$ if the measurments are with respect to the same object exactly half a year apart and angles measured with a sign.